# Something wrong with If...else

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this `user.model`

```
// user.model.ts

interface User {
  name: string
  email: string
  password: string
  is_active: boolean
}
```

And I check if email is taken and user is active before signing up with email.

```
    // If email is taken and is_active is true
    if (found && found.is_active) {
      return next(Boom.badRequest('Email is taken'))
    } else if (found && !found.is_active) {
      // If email is taken and is_active is false, ask to signin
      return next(Boom.unauthorized('Please signin to activate'))
    } else {
      const created = await service.create(data)
      res.send('OK')
    }
```

But the problem is when I tried with the email (some@one.com) that is already *registered and active*, it shows `Email is taken` which is correct. And then when I tried with the another email (any@one.com) that is *registered but not active*, it tried to insert the data and broke server because `email` column is `unique` is database (Postgres).

I tried again, but this time (any@one.com) first and (some@one.com) second. It broke again at second condition.

I guess the problem is it only works for one condition.

I also tried with `switch...case`, does not work either.

```
    switch (true) {
      case found && found.is_active:
        // If email is taken and is_active is true
        return next(Boom.badRequest('Email is taken'))
      case found && !found.is_active:
        // If email is taken and is_active is false, ask to signin
        return next(Boom.unauthorized('Please signin to activate'))
      default: {
        const created = await service.create(data)
        res.send('OK')
      }
    }
```

Please help, how do I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you register with an already registered email, it will obviously show 'Email is taken'.

Comment: Why do you have switch that is set to `true` always? It means this piece of code unnecessary. Wdyt

Comment: Did you check what data `found` has?

Comment: @ZainZafar that's a legitimate technique in javascript. The case statement that evaluates as true will run.

Comment: I think you're complicating it for yourself. Take a step back and decide what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the simple logic of those ifs/switches. Given that `found && found.is_active` and `found && !found.is_active` exhaust the logical possibilities of `found` being truthy (existing), then logically 'found' must be falsey. So the problem lies outside the code you have provided.

Comment: So emails that arent active cant be found? Considering the code you provided you should check your found logic.

Comment: @VLAZ @seeSharper @Estradiaz You guys/girls are right! It was the `found` problem, it returns `undefined` at second query. I have no idea how though, I was using Objection.js and now I'm fallback to Knex. Thanks guys/girls!

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using your `if` statements like that?

```
if (found) {
  if (found.is_active) {
    // already in use by active user
    return next(Boom.badRequest('Email is taken'))
  } else {
   // in use, but inactive
   return next(Boom.unauthorized('Please signin to activate'))
  }
else {
// not found, must create
  const created = await service.create(data)
  res.send('OK')
}
```

Comment: This is just a style change, the logic is the same. Why would it fix anything?

Comment: It rules out the possibility of it being a malformed if statement.

Comment: We can see that it isn't. The logic *for the `if` statement* is correct. Therefore, the problem is elsewhere.